# How to use Shape class in android apps?

Tags: android

I want to know how to use Shape class in android applications. If anybody knows please reply me.

Answer (score 2):

Umm, the Shape class is an abstract class. So you can only 'use' its [children](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RectShape.html).